# XMLDocument "Registry key not found" Error - C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xmldocument

When I try to parse a sample XML-File using C# and XMLDocument it throws an IO.IOException and says it didn't find the registry-key. You can find the sample XML-File here. (It's the link I give the tool in InfoFileURL. Has anyone got a fix for that problem?

```
xmlDoc.Load(InfoFileURL);

if (xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Program/Files").HasChildNodes) // IOException
{
     foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Program/Files/File"))
     {
         if (int.Parse(node.Attributes["Date"].Value) > VersionOld)
         {
              NewFile newfile = new NewFile();
              newfile.FilePath = node.Attributes["Path"].Value;
              newfile.Hash = node.Attributes["Hash"].Value;
              newfile.Date = int.Parse(node.Attributes["Date"].Value);
              newfile.WebPath = node.InnerText;

              NewFiles.Add(newfile);
          }
     }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception Detail:

  System.IO.IOException ist aufgetreten.
  HResult=2
  Message=Der angegebene Registrierungsschlüssel ist nicht vorhanden.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       bei Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
 InnerException: 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XML-File:
http://neolegends.tk/programs/test/updates.xml

<Program>
   <Changes>
       <Change Date="20130111">Heyo Mofo</Change>
   </Changes>
   <Files>
       <File Date="20130111" Hash="977d6a6c1028c1dff3b0a1a7e1604d033b7a14a7" Path="ni94512_1_DB.7z">http://neolegends.tk/programs/test/data/ni94512_1_DB.7z</File>
       <File Date="20130111" Hash="ef520d82094153930247b0d75144b77bee6e40ea" Path="Osmos.sta">http://neolegends.tk/programs/test/data/Osmos.sta</File>
   </Files>
   <Deletions>
       <Deletion Date="20130111">HITMÄN.mp3</Deletion>
   </Deletions>
</Program>
```

Comment: This isn't a question mate. What else have you tried?

Comment: You'll get the question out of what my problem is. :D

However, I'll edit it.

To your question, I already tried downloading the XML-File with WebClient and then loading the offline file into XMLDocument but no luck.

Comment: Cool, you might want to check out the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) section of the faq though. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It should not throw an IOException when selecting within an XmlDocument. The line

```
if (xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Program/Files").HasChildNodes)
```

is unnecessary because the foreach will not do anything if Program/Files does not exist. Also, you will get a null reference exception on the HasChildNodes property if xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Program/Files") returns null.

Try prefixing your xpath with "/":

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Program/Files/File"))
```

This will select from the root node. Or prefix with "//" to select anywhere within the xml:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Program/Files/File"))
```

EDIT: Your code should not be accessing the registry. Are you sure the exception is being thrown by the code you showed above? You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what registry keys are being accessed and when (by single stepping through your code and seeing what registry access Process Monitor reports).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it cleans up the code but it doesn't fix my problem. It still says 'Given Registry Key not found'...

Comment: Well, the problem is, this Code is inside a .dll File which is then being loaded by a WPF-Application to provide the testing interface so there's no own process for all this. This is the biggest block of events I could find that relate to the DLL.

http://pastebin.com/2xLFxkhs

Comment: EDIT: I just put the Code into the WPF-Application.

Okay, it gives me almost six thousand new events just for starting the tool. When I press the button, it gives me another thousand, and the last ten entrys are the actual XML-Download, as the tool says TCP Connect, TCP Receive and TCP Disconnect. However, this gives me no further information about the problem I have.